# How to achieve Task Parallelism in Spark and Scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, apache-spark-sql, future

We have a `Spark batch job`, where we are reading data from `HBase table` and apply multiple transformations and then populate the data in Cassandra[multiple tables].

We have multiple `independent tasks`, which is using the same `DataFrame` [ Hbase table data]. Basically we have several dashboards based on the same Hbase table data.

Currently everything is running `sequentially`, how to run this `parallel`?

Is it a good practice to use `Scala` `Future` to run the tasks parallel?

Comment: Spark already runs tasks in parallel.  You probably mean a spark `job` (`job` and `task`) have specific meanings in spark.

Comment: @puhlen: Spark supports data parallelization, not task parallelization, when i say task, i mean transforming the same DF into multiple ways and populate multiple cassandra tables.

Comment: I understand what you are asking, but to avoid confusion use the meaning of `job` and `task` from spark.  In spark, a Task is ta unit of parallel computation.  You are talking about spark `Job`s, not `Task`s.  A single spark job (one of your transformations into the cassandra table) is probably made up of multiple stages and many tasks.  Unfortunately I don't have the answer to your question, but I suspect there are potential problems with the independent jobs fighting each other for resources, but that's just speculation.

Comment: some actions can be performed asynchronously : https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.AsyncRDDActions

Comment: I have a similar requirement here. need to refresh couple of dataframes every few minutes, while the main process uses the data in those dataframes.  Needless to say, first thing that comes to mind is to use threads/Runnables for these refresh calls. Wonder if there is anything within  spark to achieve the same !!!